# Sending POST request in firefox addon (javascript)

Tags: javascript, post, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

With a firefox addon (javascript) I'm trying to send a POST request to a server to get a session ID back, but none of conventional methods seem to work, I already tried xmlhttprequest and getting it with forms isn't possible because it's internal code.
Is there a way to get this working, maybe even with the addon SDK?

References to my tries:

[Javascript sending data via POST in firefox addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494479/javascript-sending-data-via-post-in-firefox-addon)

[HTTP POST in javascript in Firefox Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176359/http-post-in-javascript-in-firefox-extension)

Comment: This solution here also has a XHR but for non-sdk (which can also be used in sdk) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471666/ajax-in-firefox-plugin/25514239#25514239

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the new Addon SDK you should use the new [Request API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/request) instead of XMLHttpRequest. 
The new Interface is a lot easier to use, too.

Here is a quick example:

```
// make sure this gets executed BEFORE making the Request
var Request = require("sdk/request").Request;

Request({
  url: "http://example.com/hello-world.php",
  content: { hello: 'world' },
  onComplete: function (response) {
    console.log( response.text );
  }
}).post();
```

I suggest you may have a look at this MDN Tutorial: [Getting started](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_started)